# Centre a view with respect to above view in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android

[image]

As you can see, the 3rd one, bottom view is right aligned, I want it to align centre to the above view. I don't want to group them together as I think there is a possible alternate solution

I don't think code is necessary here, If you need, pls comment below

Comment: trying giving both `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/YourTopView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/YourTopView"` and make width as `wrap content`. This would work I guess.

Comment: perfect, thanks,, this is me not thinking right. I will delete the question in 5 mins. Thanks again

Comment: I am adding this as an answer please accept and do a upvote so the others can find and get help easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :-

`app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/YourTopView" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/YourTopView"`

and make width as `wrap content`. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Contraint the bottom view's left and right with the left and right of the view above it respectively. Also contraint the top of bottom view with the bottom of the above view. This should help you out.